# ¿Por qué el botón no se activa?

Tags: javascript, html

Intento usar un botón mediante la biblioteca [`bulma.io`](http://bulma.io/documentation/), pero no logro activarlo como se hace con un botón normal.

Aquí los botones deben activarse solamente cuando se haya seleccionado uno de los radio button, pero el de bulma se queda siempre desactivado.

[En la documentación](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/button/) ellos dicen que se use el atributo `disabled` de HTML, lo cual hago, pero no puedo cambiar el estado del botón de forma dinámica.

```js
var allLogin = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=login]');
var url="";
var btnBulma=document.getElementById('btnBulma');
var btnNormal=document.getElementById('btnNormal');

allLogin.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('change', function() {
    url=this.value;
    console.log(url);
     btnBulma.disabled = false;   
     btnNormal.disabled = false;   
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" integrity="sha256-2pUeJf+y0ltRPSbKOeJh09ipQFYxUdct5nTY6GAXswA=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Pass">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="login" value="url_1">
    Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="login" value="url_2">
    Option 2
  </label>
  <a id="btnBulma" disabled="disabled" class="button is-primary is-outlined" disabled >Enviar Bulma</a> <br />
<button   id="btnNormal" disabled>Enviar Normal</button>
</form>
```

¿Sabe alguien cómo podría cambiar el estado del botón?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomado de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4538714/8663418)

Basta con que elimines el atributo `disabled`, llamando a `removeAttribute( )`:

```js
var allLogin = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=login]');
var url="";
var btnBulma=document.getElementById('btnBulma');
var btnNormal=document.getElementById('btnNormal');

allLogin.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('change', function() {
    url=this.value;
    console.log(url);
     btnBulma.removeAttribute("disabled");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" integrity="sha256-2pUeJf+y0ltRPSbKOeJh09ipQFYxUdct5nTY6GAXswA=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Name">
  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Pass">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="login" value="url_1">
    Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="login" value="url_2">
    Option 2
  </label>
  <a id="btnBulma" class="button is-primary is-outlined" disabled >Enviar Bulma</a> <br />
<button   id="btnNormal" disabled>Enviar Normal</button>
</form>
```

**Nota**: Como indica [@OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18608/oscargarcia) en los comentarios, el atributo `disabled` es un *booleano* en si mismo; no es necesario especificar `disabled="disabled`, basta con `disabled` a secas.

Comment: Mi +1. También estaría bien comentar que es mejor usar únicamente un atributo en vez de usar dos, `disabled` y `disabled="disabled"`.

Comment: Tienes razón. Lo correcto es `disabled` a secas, ¿ no ? Se supone que es *booleano*, si no recuerdo mal

Comment: Eooo genial! Muchas gracias Trauma. @OscarGarcia, sí lo tenía así, solamente `disabled`, pero hice todas las pruebas posibles a ver si funcionaba y olvidé dejarlo con sólo `disabled`.